# Disable laptop screen and use only VGA

Tags: debian, multi-monitor

I have an old laptop with a faulty screen (The screen works in random intervals). Recently I bought a screen and I thought I can use my old laptop as a media centre.

Can I disable completely my laptop's screen? I have done this for my user, but I don't know how to do this systemwise. I have installed debian stretch with th default desktop environment.

Comment: Often old laptops are easier to open. I would disconnect the flat cable going to the screen, probably lower power usage too if you do that.

Comment: There may be an option in the BIOS to output only to external screen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run the command `xrandr -q` to  shows the exact names.

```
xrandr -q | grep 'VGA\|HDMI\|DP\|LVDS'
```

This is a sample command to turn off `LVDS-1` and enable `VGA-1`:

```
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --off --output VGA-1 --auto
```

To switch back:

```
xrandr --output VGA-1 --off --output LVDS-1 --auto
```

Comment: To make the change permanent one can edit the file `/etc/default/grub` followed by the command`update-grub`, and disable laptop's display changing this parameter: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=LVDS-1:d"`

Comment: I see why Dmitry's comment (above) has as many upvotes as the accepted answer. I'll suggest an edit to include his information in the answer. It was the full picture of what I was looking to accomplish (and perhaps what the OP was looking to accomplish as well).

Comment: @Mike Welcome , I encourage you to post it as answer, it is more than an edit , it should be an answer.

Comment: @GAD3R, fair enough. I'm more than happy to post it as another answer. Alternatively, if you'd prefer, you can take my answer, and you can edit your post if you'd prefer. I'd honestly see you (and Dmitry) get the credit, since I'm just cobbling together _your_ information.

Answer (score 2):

To permanently disable the laptop screen, modify `/etc/default/grub` and change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to something like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=LVDS-1:d"
```

where `LVDS-1` is the screen you want to disable (obtained via `xrandr`).

After that, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.